# Can infinitely many points on the boundary $C$ of a domain be singular without $C$ being a natural boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, analytic-continuation

This question was asked in my complex analysis quiz and I was unable to do it.

Can infinitely many points on the boundary $C$ of a domain  be singular without $C$ being a natural boundary ?

I thnik it can be as on the boundary there are uncountable many points and if countably finite points are singular then it's not a problem as natural boundary in that case can be extended as there are points that are still regular.

But I want it to be checked. So I posted here.

Useful definitions: Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic in a domain $D$. A point $z_1$ is said to be a regular point of $f(z)$ if the function element $(f,D)$ can be analytically continued along some curve from a point in $D$ to the point
$z_1$.

Any boundary point of $D$ that is not a regular point of $f(z)$ is said to be a singular point of $f(z)$.

Comment: What if the boundary is a circle and all the points are on one half of the circle.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Is there something else that is given in this question? For example, has a particular function been given?

Comment: @LeeMosher No particular function is given.

Comment: @LeeMosher I have rechecked it and I wrote as it was given in quiz.

Comment: If that's the case, then you should probably also include in your question the definition of a "singular point on the boundary of a domain". I'm not sure what that would mean from a purely topological standpoint (I'm also not sure what it might mean from a complex analytic point of view).

Comment: Try the function $\tan z$ on the upper half-plane.  It has infinitely many poles on the real axis, but the real line is not a natural boundary.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to ask whether infinitely many points on the boundary ($C$) of a domain can be singular without *part* of $C$ being a natural boundary.  Obviously *all* of $C$ needn't be a natural boundary... just take part of a natural boundary that contains infinitely many singular points, and then join the endpoints through the interior of the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega = \mathbb C \setminus [(-\infty,0]\cup \{1\}].$ Then $\partial \Omega = (-\infty,0]\cup \{1\}.$ Let $f(z)=\log z,$ the principal branch of the logarithm. Then $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and every $x\in (-\infty,0]$ is a singular point of $f.$ But $\partial \Omega$ is not a natural boundary for $f,$ as $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $1.$